# CR / LF character conversion when trying to parse XML

Tags: swift, xml, unicode

I am trying to manipulate an XML Document.  I am using [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML).

One of the elements is:

```xml
<DigestValue>MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEINw11if3rwKZpjXua6DautZ/ciHeGATrbbGRpeoE&#xD;
83NQ</DigestValue>
```

It is being changed into:

```xml
<DigestValue>MDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEINw11if3rwKZpjXua6DautZ/ciHeGATrbbGRpeoE
&#10;83NQ</DigestValue>
```

How can I preserve the string representation?

Comment: What is the reason you want it to remain the same? They are equivalent, one just uses the hexadecimal representation of the character instead of the decimal one. Any XML parser will treat them the same.

Comment: @wasmachien unfortunately the parser I am dealing with does not consider them equivalent.

Comment: @desertSniper87 Then the parser you are using is broken. Use a different one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Better said than done brother.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `xmlEscaped` function of the AEXMLElement Class.

```swift
public extension String {
    /// String representation of self with XML special characters escaped.
    var xmlEscaped: String {
    ///  we need to make sure "&" is escaped first. Not doing this may break escaping the other characters
        var escaped = replacingOccurrences(of: "&", with: "&amp;", options: .literal)

        /// replace the other five special characters
        let escapeChars = ["\r": "&#xD;"]
        
        for (char, echar) in escapeChars {
            escaped = escaped.replacingOccurrences(of: char, with: echar, options: .literal)
        }
        
        return escaped
    }
}
```